# TextView onClick not responding to single tap

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` with the following assignment code:

```
Answer1TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Answer1TextView.setOnClickListener(answer1TextViewListener);
```

and here is my onClickListener:

```
private  OnClickListener answer1TextViewListener = new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(Answer1Win){
            Toast.makeText(QuizScreen.this,"Correct ",2).show();
        } else
        {
            Toast.makeText(QuizScreen.this,"Incorrect, Pick Another Answer",2).show();
        }
    }
};
```

My problem is the Toast only is displayed after a double tap. I cannot find a setting the drives this behavior, what could be set wrong to not display after a single tap.

Comment: Does it work for both Correct and Incorrect, even after 2 taps?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The first click just sets the focus to the TextBox then the second click actually gets handled as a click. Rather than using an onClickListener, you may have better luck with an [onFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29)

Comment: Alternatively, just set `android:focusable="false"` to the TextView in the XML, or call `Answer1TextView.setFocusable(false);`.

Comment: KC,   .setFocusable(false);  fixed the problem,  thanks for the assist.

Comment: KC thanks for your suggestion. .setFocusable(false); worked for me. Great. Keep posting useful stuff. thanks again

Comment: FYI Setting focusable to false will disable setError()

Comment: @MikeWallaceDev then how to display errorMessage in focusable false TextView or EditText???

Comment: Thank you all for this rich conversation.

Comment: @Chirag Savsani: I solved it by calling 1. setFocusable(true); and  2. setFocusableInTouchMode(true); before calling setError method and in the xml do not set setFocusable neither focusableInTouchMode

It worked with me, this way. Hope I answered you in a good manner.

Answer (score 3):

As Chris said, the first tap *focuses* the `TextView` and the second tap *clicks* it.

Setting `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` fixes the problem for touchscreens but without breaking functionality for non-touchscreen devices.

If you were to simply use `android:focusable="false"` that would prevent, for example, d-pad users from clicking the view *at all*.

Comment: Looks to me like the d-pad isn't really relevant in today's world. I don't think `focusable="false"` will prevent functionality for any disabled users, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @CorayThan Given that both attributes are equally easy to set, personally I'd rather choose the one that doesn't break functionality on certain devices - even if those devices are less common at the moment. Things change (e.g. android TVs might become more common) and assuming that your users are all touchscreen might well cause headaches in the future - and in this case there's no immediate benefit to it anyway. (disclaimer: I haven't kept up to date with Android so assuming the attributes still do what they used to when I wrote the answer)

Answer (score 2):

The issue may be that textIsSelectable is true. Set `textIsSelectable="false"` for the TextView in XML.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do that is `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: TextView is clickable by default. This probably isn't the issue.

Comment: I have tried it as I got same problem. putting ^ that, solve my problem. My TextView only need 1 tap to respond.

Answer (score 0):

use `OnTouchListener` instead `onFocusListener` triggers twice when you enter and leaves the key