# A loop with setOnClickListener at Android Studio

Tags: java, android, loops, onclicklistener

Hey so I'm trying to make a simple code that makes the visibility of a layout visible once an image been clicked twice or more.
Sadly my code doesn't work, but I don't understand why.

Here's my code -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView logoIMG;
LinearLayout adminLinear;

int cnt = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    logoIMG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    adminLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adminLinear);


    adminLinear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    adminLinear.setEnabled(false);


    while (adminLinear.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        logoIMG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cnt >= 2) {
                    adminLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    adminLinear.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this while-event code is not a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting onClickListener in your while loop, will endlessly loop and keep on trying to add new Listener, which will cause issue.

Do following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    logoIMG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cnt >= 2) {
                    adminLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    adminLinear.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work sadly.. it just sets the visibility of the layout to Visible right away, without any clicks.

Comment: Updated the answer. Removed while loop. Try now

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly good. Didn't think it's that simple lol

Comment: Great! Yeah. Some time happens :-D

Answer (score 0):

Your code just gets stuck in an infinite loop. Setting an onClickListener once is enough. Remove the loop around setOnClickListener altogether, or at least replace it with a conditional (if).

Answer (score 0):

"The first click just sets the focus to the Image then the second click actually gets handled as a click. "

try setting `android:focusable="false" or true`. vice versa

[Check this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332827/textview-onclick-not-responding-to-single-tap/8332918#8332918)